# Why is this not creating a table?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table on mysql 5.5 with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `markets` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

But I get the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
      01   `updated_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
      01   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
      01 ) ENGINE' at line 4
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I can't reproduce that error, see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u5aN5RJsRsT3i6K81aiT1p/0

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @NicoHaase Works fine in 5.7 but not 5.5.

Comment: Does https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134156/why-does-this-sql-work-on-one-version-of-mysql-server-but-not-another help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
`created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
```

try

```
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Ok, this fixed it. My issue was doing `mysqldump` from 5.7 and importing into 5.5. What I don't understand is I've been doing this (using a ruby script) for years without this error. Perhaps my local mysqldump has started adding the `(6)`?

Comment: As MySQL gets updated, the compatibility with older versions gets diminished. 5.5 is pretty creaky old at this point and is worth updating.